# JavaScript Help requird for getting the dynamic values from onclick

Tags: javascript, dynamic, onclick

I am creatind 20 dynamic div , on page load attaching onclick event to each div to alert its id but problem is on clicking any div only last div id is alerted plz help.

For example on clicking on fist div is alerting last div id.

Required result is onclick on a div should alert its own id.

Full code is given bellow.

Thanks in advance.

```
 <html>
<head>
<script>
function __createElement(tag, cls, id, name)
{
 var ele;
 ele = document.createElement(tag);
 if(cls!="" && cls!=undefined)
  ele.className = cls;
 if(id != "" && id!=undefined)
  ele.id = id;
 if(name!= "" && name!=undefined)
  ele.name = name;
 return ele;
}
function test()
{
 for(var i = 0;i<20;i++)
 { 
  var div = __createElement("div" ,"test" ,i+"test");
  document.getElementById("cont").appendChild(div);
  div.innerHTML = "Content"+i;  
  div.onclick = function ()
  {
   alert(i+"test");
  }
 }
}
setTimeout("test()",1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id=cont >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this a variable closure issue use this instead:

```
  div.onclick = function (num)
  {
   return function(){
       alert(num+"test");
   };
  }(i);
```

Comment: Thanks .. it works ... i also found one solution div.onclick = function ()
  {
   alert(this.id);
  }

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem once.  Just remember: the value of `i` is now 20 across the entire scope of the `test()` function.  But, the `innerHTML` value of each div is now set as you'd expect.  So use that `innerHTML` value reference instead.

Comment: @druveen: referencing `id` as you said in your comment to The Scrum Meister's answer would do it.  `alert(i)` gives the current value of `i`, which by the end of your `for` loop is `20`.  But the element attributes, as long as they're not an anon function, are already hard set.